Formatting Micro SD card issue
I'm trying to format a 64GB Micro SD card into 70% portable storage and 30% internal storage. My phone runs Android 6, it's rooted with Magisk and I installed TWRP. Unfortunately, I can't successfully do it; I keep getting this error:
C:\Windows\system32>adb shell
shell@j3xnlte:/ $ sm has-adoptable
WARNING: linker: app_process: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
WARNING: linker: zygisk: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
true
shell@j3xnlte:/ $ sm list-disks
WARNING: linker: app_process: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
WARNING: linker: zygisk: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
disk:179_128
shell@j3xnlte:/ $ sm partition disk:179_128 mixed 70
WARNING: linker: app_process: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
WARNING: linker: zygisk: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Thread Binder_B gave up waiting for partitionMixed after 180000ms
1|shell@j3xnlte:/ $

It also doesn't work when you try it as 100% internal or portable. I tried formatting it as ext3/ext4/exFAT in TWRP and then using adb but it didn't help. I'm unable to find any fix on the XDA forum/Reddit. I'm pretty sure the Micro SD card itself isn't at fault as I was able to format it successfully using a different phone. (These two "unsupported flags" errors don't seem to be related to the problem).
Update:
I still can't get adb to format any drive on this phone (I encounter the same error), but I did manage to do it using a different method. First, I wiped the drive using TWRP and then formatted it using the built-in Android formatting tool. I had tried this before, but each time it would either get stuck forever at 20% or make 100% of the internal storage invisible to MTP and only suitable for app storage. However, this time it somehow worked - I have no idea why. MTP and root file manager shows only one drive of 58.90GB, and it behaves like the default internal storage. I will leave this post open as I didn't really solve the problem but more like got around it. Thanks for all the help (and grammar correction of this post :D ).

Based on the model, looks like you have a Samsung Galaxy J3 2016? Possibly related: How to adopt SD card as internal storage on Samsung devices?

The error is known for Android 6: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/5589 Can you use root permissions via su in an adb shell or does this trigger the same error?
